# angular14 - animating the toggling of a child component with `*ngIf`

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-animations

**TL;DR**: i'm having trouble animating the addition/removal of a child component in an Angular14 template. i've been stuck on this for a few days.

### explanation of the problem

i'm kind of new to Angular and stuck on this bit. i have a parent component called `artiste` and a child `artiste-item-detail`. `artiste` displays the name of different items in an `*ngFor` loop. upon clicking on one of those items, the child template for `artiste-item-detail` is called using an `*ngIf`. what i'm trying to do is to animate the addition of the child component.

the best thing i've managed to do is defining states for `*` and `void` and then triggering animations from `* => void` and `void => *` (see the end of this post) but this is hardly optimal and i'd like to understand what i'm doing wrong ??

### tldr: how my code works

basically, upon clicking on a `<button>` in `artiste-component`, an item is selected by its id which activates the projection of content from the child template. clicking this button also switches the `state` variable from `"visible"` to `"hidden"`, which should trigger the animation.

i've followed several tutorials (especially [this one](https://www.usefuldev.com/post/Angular:%20using%20animations%20with%20NgIf)) and looked up all stackoverflow entries on this problem, but had no success.

### templates and code

`artiste.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
  /* ... */
  animations: [
    trigger("toggleArtistItemDetail", [
      state("visible", style({
        height: 100,
        "max-height": "200px",
        opacity: 1
      })),
      state("hidden", style({
        height: "0px",
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition("hidden => visible", [
        animate("0.5s 0.1s ease-in")
      ]),
      transition("hidden => hidden", [
        animate("0.3s 0.1s ease-out")
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {
  id?: any;
  db?: ArtistDb;
  selectedItemId?: number|string;
  state?: State;
  
  /* 
     constructors, initialisation methods and other 
     functions are skipped for clarity
  */
  
  /* event handlers */
  onSelect(itemId: number|string): void {
    /*
      this selects an item which will be displayed
      by `artiste-item-detail` and switches the
      state which should trigger the animation
    */
    if (
      this.selectedItemId !== itemId
    ) {
      this.selectedItemId = itemId;
      this.state = "visible";
    } else {
      this.selectedItemId = undefined;
      this.state = "hidden";
    }
  }
  
  animationDone(event: AnimationEvent) {
    if (event.fromState === "visible" && event.toState === "hidden") {
      this.selectedItemId = undefined;
    }
  }
}
```

template for the above component (`artiste.component.html`)

```html
<div *ngFor="let artist of db | keyvalue">
  <!-- ... -->
  <div>
    <ul id="items-list">
    
      <li *ngFor="let item of artist['value']['items'] | keyvalue">
        <!--  
          when a client clicks on the button, an item
          is selected and this information is passed to
          artist-item-detail.component.ts and 
          <app-artist-item-detail>    
        -->
        
        <!-- button for a single item -->
        <button type="button"
                (click)="onSelect(item.key)"
                [class.selected]="item.key === selectedItemId"
        >
          <!-- some text -->
        </button>
        
        <app-artist-item-detail [item]="item"
                                *ngIf="item.key === selectedItemId"
                                [@toggleArtistItemDetail]="state"
                                (@toggleArtistItemDetail.done)="animationDone($event)">
          <!-- details on a single item. see `artist-item-detail` -->
        </app-artist-item-detail>
      </li>
  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`artiste-item-detail.component`

```js
export class ArtistItemDetailComponent {
  private _item: ArtistItem = {};
  
  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void { }
  
  get item(): ArtistItem {
    /*
      get the current item to send it to the template
    */
    return this._item;
  }
  
  @Input() set item(input: any) {
    /*
      set the current item on click
    */
    if (input) {
      this._item = input;
    }
  }
}
```

`artiste-item-detail.component.html`

```html
<div *ngIf="item">
  <div *ngFor="let i of item | keyvalue">
    <!-- stuffthat will be displayed -->
  </div>

  <ng-content #itemDetailContent></ng-content>
</div>
```

### what i've tried / what works

i've tried placing the animations and defining my `state` variable and all animations on the child component, but this didn't work (i suppose it is because when the item is deselected, it is removed from the DOM and all animations thus cease to exist.

the best thing i've come up with is setting my animations as such in the parent component `artiste.component`, but it's not ideal and will probably cause problem when there are multiple animations on the same page :

```js
animations: [
    trigger("toggleArtistItemDetail", [
      state("*", style({
        height: 100,
        "max-height": "200px",
        opacity: 1
      })),
      state("void", style({
        height: "0px",
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition("void => *", [
        animate("0.5s 0.1s ease-in")
      ]),
      transition("* => void", [
        animate("0.3s 0.1s ease-out")
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

what am i doing wrong ??